# incorrect horizontal lineup for table

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/tbnzaga9/

```css
#smenu a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #A9A9A9;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  width: 30%;
  left: 1%;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 60%;
}

#smenu table tr td p {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id='smenu'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th> Title</th>
      <th class='right'> Date</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='button'><a href="gradecalc.html">test</a></td>
      <td class='right'>
        <p>4/27</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I was making a list of separate websites and the dates they were made, but I can't get them to line up! I tried `float:left` and `display: inline-block`, but it's just not lining up. Any suggestions?

Also - is there a better way than using a table?

Comment: remove `position: absolute` from `.button and .right`

Comment: but then the size I want isn't there...

Comment: Browser takes out elements having `position: absolute` from normal flow. You shouldn't use this property everywhere... Try other variants like setting some `width` on `table` and setting column alignment with `text-align` css property.

Comment: `table{
  width: 500px;
}`
sets table width

Comment: Further do not override styles of tables cell (`td`) with css `display` property. This is bad practice. Add some element like `span` or `div` if necessary.

Comment: This is almost perfect, how can I set the height of each box? adding `.button { height: 25px; }` isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try these change in CSS.

```
    #smenu a {
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .button:hover {
      background-color: #A9A9A9;
    }
    .button {
      border: 1px solid black;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: #d3d3d3;
    }
    td {
      text-align: center;
      width: 200px;
      height:25px;
    }
    #smenu table tr td p {
      //display: inline-block;
      //float: left;
    }
```

Comment: how can I change the height of each row?

Comment: Use height:25px; in CSS for td. Set your required height in px. A helpful link for you is https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `<p></p>` by `<div></div>` or use a css reset sheet to clear the paragraph doing a line break. Also, I think tables are ok to do things like this, but limit you more. If you really wanted to you could mimic a table with some divs where you have your rows and in each one have your columns you could have differents classes by rows and by column in different rows.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove all "position:absolute".
Given that you have tabular data, it makes sense to just use a regular table tag.

I've also added the following styles:

```
.right {
  padding-right: 60%;
}

#smenu table {
  width:100%;
}
 .right p {
   margin:0px;
 }

 th {
   text-align: left;
 }
```

You can see the changes here:
https://jsfiddle.net/tbnzaga9/2/